# .get_text() doesn't work in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Why soup does not recognize the `.get_text()` function to remove the HTML elements?

I keep getting this error message:

```
  File "./bondora.py", line 45, in <module>
    onlineumsaetze.append(td.get_text())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/bs4/element.py", line 2173, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get_text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from selenium import webdriver
from seleniumrequests import Firefox
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

onlineumsaetze = []

url = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')
tab = soup.find('table', {"class":"table js-filter-table"})


for row in tab.find_all('tr'):
    td = row.find_all("td")
    onlineumsaetze.append(td.get_text())


print(onlineumsaetze)
```

Answer (score 2):

`.find_all()` returns a list of BS objects, and you cannot extract the text from a list using `.get_text()`. You have to iterate again in that list and for each element use `get_text()`.

```
for row in tab.find_all('tr'):
  td = row.find_all("td")
  
  for element in td:
    onlineumsaetze.append(element.get_text())
```